# "Incomplete definition. 'foreign' required." on making migration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony6

I'm trying to run `symfony console make:migration` (also tried with `php bin/console make:migration`, just in case), but I'm encountering an error :

> Incomplete definition. 'foreign' required.

This seems to be caused by one of my OneToMany's field, which I tried to modify to fit my project better.

Once I got this error, I tried putting a debug message where the error was triggered, it told me the error comes from my *Team* entity.

*Note : my project is made of 3 entities : Team, Patch and Game. One team can have many patches. One game can also have many patches. One patch can be linked to many games.*

When I tried to create the OneToMany field between *Team* and *Patch*, I told symfony to create "team_id" in Patch, but it turned out to be names team_id_id, which I didn't want. To correct that, I renamed the database field, and did some adjustments in my Patch entity code; adding "name: 'team_id'", here is the part :

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'patch_ids')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'team_id', nullable: false)]
private ?Team $team_id = null;
```

It worked at the time, but it seems to cause some problems when I try to add some other fields to Game (probably to any entity actually)

This is my first post, so feel free to ask for more details if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this shouldn't be about best practices, but it somewhat is.

Working with an ORM has advantages and disadvantages - obviously - and you should be aware. Sometimes, ORMs will deduct the database structure from the definitions in code. Doctrine, the ORM that symfony uses, does that.

That means, if your database is somehow different from what it expects after reading your code, it might choke on changes. Also, if you bring your database into an inconsistent state, you have to fix it yourself.

**What might have happened**

A migration with relation fields will also add foreign keys, such that entries in a field (like `patch.team_id` or `patch.team_id_id`) are checked against the actual primary keys of the other table (like `team.id` or `team.team_id`, depending on your naming schema).

If you somehow managed to only rename the field but not remove the foreign key and add the correct version of the foreign key, you will not be able to add any more columns, since the schema is invalid. Doctrine gives the foreign keys names, that are hashes of its parts, such that there are no name collisions. If the colum name changed, the hash would too, so the chances are, the foreign key is wrong in some way.

**Solving the problems**

The correct way (for reference in the future) would have been to *roll back* the migration that introduced the change you didn't like, then remove the migration, fix the problem in your code / annotation / attributes and create a new migration. Doctrine does what you tell it to do, but you might not be writing the stuff that you mean (from doctrine's perspective).

So that is your short-term way to salvation, revert the changes in your migration, especially the foreign keys - if you don't know what those are: read up.

Using the check mappings/schema abilities of doctrine might help, too.

**Suggestions**

Understand Doctrine (maybe ORMs in general). In Doctrine you should never have a *field* (php property) `team_id`, even though you have a *column* `team_id` (db column). The field should be named `team`, as it is a `Team` entity, of type `?Team`. Doctrine will add `_id` to the column name, if the field contains an entity. (and this would remove your need to add JoinColumn names)

*Doctrine* maps the object (relation) layer - "a patch might have a team" - to the database layer: "the patch table has a `team_id`, which is a foreign key referencing `team.id`" and it can make most of the database stuff easier. The result should usually be, that you should not give much thought, how anything is in database and just write object-oriented code.

You should also not write SQL but DQL (doctrine query language), the object oriented alternative. Doctrine will take that and turn it into SQL. That's the ORM way. At the end, your code might look more elegant, if you follow the ways that doctrine has carved out for you. (But it's always a matter of opinion, obviously)

The disadvantages of an ORM are usually that although it's nicer for all the trivial stuff, it's so much harder to do the complicated stuff, not intended by the ORM (doctrine in this case) and that some queries/mechanisms are inefficient and to fix those is quite complicated (e.g. n+1 problem). If you want to write more elaborate queries and still all the good parts of doctrine, you might stumble over some ugly rocks. (database-specific functions, usually).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which led me to `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update`, solving my problem.
I won't ever have this problem again